# update div statesman change state of the object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, states

I want to update the `div` when a transition changes my object.

So I have in my view the objects rendered:

```
<% things.each do |order| %>
  <div class='current_state' data-id="<%= thing.id %>">
  <% thing.state %>
<% end %>
```

I want to update `things.state` when it changes. Those changes occur by different logic in the application (ruby), using `statesman`.

I know the basics of ajax and I don't know if that is posible.
Until now, I have done:

- I have a jquery code that gets the number of elements I have rendered and I get the id for each of them in a for bucle, doing an ajax call:

  ```
  function updateStatus() {
  var many_things = $("div[class*='current_state']").length;

  for (i=0; i<many_things-1; i++) {
  var thing_id = $('.current_state')[i].attributes['data-id'].value;
  $.ajax({
  url: '/things/update_status',
  data: { thing_id: thing_id }
   });

  setTimeout(updateStatus(), 10000);
  }
  ```

  As you can see, I want to do a polling request to get the `div` updated.
- I get the `params` in my controller with the id, so I can find the object.
  `@thing`, and get the current state for that object.

In my partial I send `@thing`, but it's received as `nil` or just not received.
If I put some text in the partial is working in the view.
Something like:

```
<%= p 'something' if !@thing %>
```

From here, I don't know how to get each state attribute and print it in the correct object for each of them.

Another option I thought is to launch a call from the `after_transition` callback of `statesman`. But I don't know if this is possible.

I hope to have been clear in the explanation of the issue.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: My question was more about a concept question. It’s not like something is not working for some typo error.
So I was'nt precise writing the example.
I don’t know how to achive to render this status for each correspondent object.
This ajax call goes to my controller succesfully.
In my rails controller update_status, I get the `@thing`.
 js file: `update_status.js.erb`:
   ` $('#current_state').html('<%= j render('things/update_status') %>');`
the partial:    
`<div class="some_fancy_style current_state" >`
       `<%= @thing.current_state if @thing %>`
    </div>`
`@thing` here is always nil.

Answer (score 0):

First, **output your state** with `<%=` instead of `<%`, and close your `<div>` while you're at it.

```
<% things.each do |order| %>
  <div class='current_state' data-id="<%= thing.id %>">
    <%= thing.state %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Second, where does `things` come from? and where did `@thing` end up? They're **two different variables**. I'm guessing you want to call it `@things`, and set it in the controller.

Third, your ajax call actually has to do something, with a `success` setting. You're making a request, but the **response goes nowhere**. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/things/update_status',
  data: { thing_id: thing_id },
  success: function(data, etc) { change_the_page(); },
});
```

NB. The Done Thing would be for `/things/update_status` to be a `PATCH` or `PUT` request, rather than a `GET` (ajax's default), if it actually changes something. You'd need to fix that in `config/routes.rb`.

FYI, in `<%= p 'something' if !@thing %>`, the `=` will output `something` to the *browser*, and the `p` will output `"something"` to the *terminal*.

Comment: My question was more about a concept question. It’s not like something is not working for some typo error. So I was'nt precise writing the example. I don’t know how to achieve to render this status for each correspondent object. This ajax call goes to my controller succesfully. In my rails controller update_status, I get the @thing. js file: update_status.js.erb: ` $('#current_state').html('<%= j render('things/update_status') %>');` the partial: <div class="some_fancy_style current_state" > <%= @thing.current_state if @thing %> </div>` @thing here is always nil. –

Comment: Just a heads-up then: Stack Overflow prefers you *"only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* [[source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)].

Comment: If you're saying you want your browser to refresh [part of] *itself* when something changes in the *database,* you only have a couple of options: you can either have your client poll the server (refresh itself often), or you can set up a websocket connection (which is rather complicated and generally not necessary). Normally, HTTP requests can only come from the client.

Comment: Ok, here I am doing polling using setTimeout but I cannot get the the div updated for each 'thing'. I need a way to identify each item that has the same class. I will check 'pusher' (https://pusher.com/) for websocket. Thanks